# Multiple files opened as a single tab?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, package-management, text-editing, packages

I'm trying to have a single tab open with more than one file, such that when I run bulk replaces, searches, or other macros, and such that when  I want to browse through my application, I won't have to change tabs.

It should simply look something like this:

```
----begin file: a.java
//a.java
package alphabet;
public class a{
}
----end file: a.java
----begin file: b.java
//b.java
package alphabet;
public class b{
}
----end file: b.java
.
.
.
----begin file: z.java
...
```

This seems terribly convenient, so I wonder if there shouldn't already be something in existence?  Of course, this wouldn't be 'pane'-based browsing.  It would simply read like a normal tab.

Comment: I'm not sure about notepad++ but I know in sublime you can search directories and return all hits in a single file, which gives you part of what you are looking for.

Comment: notepad++ does search and replace across open tabs.  It doesn't look like it does for macros though.

Comment: @Paul Looking for this specifically.  Familiar with the all-open-files `search and replace` functions.